# GrantOfflineAccess auth code returned is throwing bad request "redirect_uri_mismatch" when using to exchange for tokens in c#

Tags: .net-core, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-api-js-client

I am using gapi client in Angular to make requests to google.
I have my code as follows.
[image]

This code is returning the auth code from google but When i am using this auth code to generate tokens in C# .NET Core application it is throwing Bad Request "redirect_uri" error

```
Error:"redirect_uri_mismatch", Description:"Bad Request", Uri:""
```

The code in the .NET Application is as follows

[image]

Please help me in resolving this issue. I did not find any single clue on how to proceed further

Comment: please edit your question and include your code not a picture of your code

Comment: are you sure this is .net core?  GoogleAutorizationCodeFlow shouldn't work with .net core.

Comment: @DalmTo Yes I am 100 percent sure this is .NET Core I am able to use googleAuthorizationCodeFlow to exchange auth code with tokens i.e  Auth codes generated through REST Api calls by calling https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth URL

Comment: are you using a console application, or asp .net core?

Comment: ASP .NET Core 3.1 Web api @DalmTo.

Answer (score 0):

For starters for asp .net core you should be following this [Configure your application to use Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#configure-your-application-to-use-google.apis.auth.aspnetcore3)

Fyi background info:

- GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync (installed application)
- GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow (asp .net MVC)

Neither of these methods is going to allow you to pass in a authorization code and exchange it for a access token out of the box. I could probably get it to work without to much trouble with the asp .net it will require that you create your own implementation of idatastore that would accept the authorization code and finish off the oauth dance for you but you would need to set up the redirect URIs properly.  IMO: You should not be passing the authorization code around to the back end anyway.

With .net core im not sure that's even possible, to pass the library a authorization code and have it complete the dance.

## Why?

Another issue will be the fact that you using two different methods to try and create this which i dont think is going to work either.  You need to either authenticate purely with angular or authenticate purely with .net core.  Pick one dont try and mix them.

TBH im not even sure the google api js client supports offline access as pure JavaScript is client sided and wouldn't allow for it.

Comment: @DalmTo I agree with what is said above. But I have a scenario where you need to give offline access to the scopes. I found out that authInstance().grantOfflineScopes() method in GAPI produces auth code in angular which gives you the ability to access in API

Comment: Why not just request offline access from .net core?  why do you need angular for this?

Comment: Is there a way to input user credentials from API side.

Comment: Im not sure i understand the question.   If your using Asp .net core just follow this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#configure-your-application-to-use-google.apis.auth.aspnetcore3  by default it should be granting offline access but i will have to double check, and im not sure where it stores its users you may have to set that up.

Comment: Okay @DalmTo Thank you.

Comment: if you have any issues check my profile there are several ways to contact me 

Answer (score 0):

The server redirect uri should be the same as the origin of your angular app, and it should be whitelisted in your google client (both for origin and redirect)

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core 7 such error means missed call to `app.UseAuthentication()`